Deciphering Python code: {n:i for i, n in enumerate(nums1)}
While watching a Neetcode video explaining a Leetcode problem 496, I happened to see this code:
{n:i for i, n in enumerate(nums1)}

Does anyone know that this means? A detailed breakdown would be helpful though not absolutely necessary.
Thanks in advance.
I just have largely been browsing reading some articles on list comprehension.

Can you be more specific about what you do and don't understand? The dictionary comprehension? Unpacking? The enumerate method itself?

Sorry, no, but you first. Please explain everything you know about the code you posted until there is a feature that puzzles you.

docs.python.org should be your first stop for questions about basic syntax.

The outer bit is a dict comprehension, which sets as key and value the reverse of the source. enumerate() adapts an internal iterator (nums1) by pairing them with their 0-indexed position in the stream. So at a high level this is an index: it creates a mapping of the values in nums1 to their position.

That creates a dictionary with key n (which is the n in the iterable nums1), and a value of i (which is the numeric iteration that n is found in the iterable).
For example:
mylist = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
print({n:i for i, n in enumerate(mylist)})

prints: {'apples':0, 'oranges':1, 'bananas':2}
(I agree with others in the comments that you should explain more about what isn't making sense.)
